# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when HDFS file creating

Tags: scala, file, hdfs

I have HDFS and some text, I want to create file with text. I tried to use HDFS api and `FSDataOutputStream`, but got an exception. Could you help me please resolve it.

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS: hdfs:/user/user1, expected: file:///
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:647)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.pathToFile(RawLocalFileSystem.java:82)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirsWithOptionalPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:513)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.mkdirs(RawLocalFileSystem.java:499)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.mkdirs(ChecksumFileSystem.java:594)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:909)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:890)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:776)
    at com.example.FileBuilder$.buildFile(FileBuilder.scala:23)
```

The code is

```
    val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
    val path = new Path(s"hdfs:////user/" + "fileName.sql")
    val fsDataOutputStream = fs.create(path)

    val outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fsDataOutputStream, "UTF-8")
    val bufferedWriter     = new BufferedWriter(outputStreamWriter)

    bufferedWriter.write(data)

    bufferedWriter.close()
    outputStreamWriter.close()
    fsDataOutputStream.close()
```

Comment: I think if you specify `fs.default.name` in Configuration and set path without prefix, the problem should gone away: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334338/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-wrong-fs-expecte

Answer (score 1):

I think there is some problem with the file path. Can you test by replace below portion of code in yours.

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(<url:port>), configuration);
Path filePath = new Path("/user/fileName.sql");
val fsDataOutputStream = fs.create(path)
```